# No module named 'sqlalchemy.sql'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I downloaded the sqlalchemy file using import sqlalchemy in my venv, however i am getting this error below.installed sqlalchemy and flashsqlalchemy in my local python environment which i have already activated.

---

```
  ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
  Cell In[12], line 7
  5 cf.go_offline() # will make cufflinks offline
  6 cf.set_config_file(offline=False, world_readable=True)
  7 import sqlalchemy

 File ~\anaconda3\envs\pythonlab\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py:13
 10 from typing import Any
 12 from . import util as _util
 13 from .engine import AdaptedConnection as AdaptedConnection
 14 from .engine import BaseRow as BaseRow
 15 from .engine import BindTyping as BindTyping

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\pythonlab\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py:18
  1 # engine/__init__.py
  2 # Copyright (C) 2005-2024 the SQLAlchemy authors and contributors
  3 # <see AUTHORS file>
  4 #
  5 # This module is part of SQLAlchemy and is released under
  6 # the MIT License: https://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
  8 """SQL connections, SQL execution and high-level DB-API interface.
  9 
 10 The engine package defines the basic components used to interface
```

(...)
15
16 """
18 from . import events as events
19 from . import util as util
20 from .base import Connection as Connection

```
 File ~\anaconda3\envs\pythonlab\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\events.py:19
 16 from typing import Type
 17 from typing import Union
 19 from .base import Connection
 20 from .base import Engine
 21 from .interfaces import ConnectionEventsTarget

 File ~\anaconda3\envs\pythonlab\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:30
 27 from typing import TypeVar
 28 from typing import Union
 30 from .interfaces import BindTyping
 31 from .interfaces import ConnectionEventsTarget
 32 from .interfaces import DBAPICursor

 File ~\anaconda3\envs\pythonlab\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\interfaces.py:38
 36 from ..pool import Pool
 37 from ..pool import PoolProxiedConnection
 38 from ..sql.compiler import Compiled as Compiled
 39 from ..sql.compiler import Compiled  # noqa
 40 from ..sql.compiler import TypeCompiler as TypeCompiler
```

ModuleNotFoundError: **No module named 'sqlalchemy.sql'**

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python ?

Comment: yes. I was able to find  a sloution by opening a different environment and donwloading a lower version of jupyter notebook.